# Transform nested collection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, collections, laravel-collection

I have a nested collection that I want to transform, pulling some keys "up a level" and discarding some other keys.

Every item in the collection has an allergens property.

```
"allergens": [
        {
            "id": 2001,
            "info": "Allergy advice",
            "status": "does_contain",
            "product_id": 71576,
            "allergen_id": 1,
            "allergen": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Celery"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2002,
            "info": "Allergy advice",
            "status": "may_contain",
            "product_id": 71576,
            "allergen_id": 11,
            "allergen": {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Peanuts"
            }
        }
    ],
```

I need to make each items allergens property, look like

```
"allergens": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Celery"
            "status": "does_contain",
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Peanuts"
            "status": "does_contain",
        },
    ],
```

I've tried the following:

```
$collection = $collection->transform(function ($item, $key) {
    $item->allergens = $item->allergens->map(function ($allergen) {
        return [
            'id' => $allergen->allergen->id,
            'name' => $allergen->allergen->name,
            'status' => $allergen->status,
        ];
    });
    
    return $item;
});
```

But it doesn't overwrite the `allergens` property

Comment: is it possible to provide entire collection so we can test directly. have you tried replacing  $item->allergens->map to  $item->allergens->transform

Comment: Switching the allergens `map()` to `transform()` resolves, the issue, which would suggest that modifying the item in place, rather than returning a new collection and updating the `$item->allergerns` property is a suitable fix. They *why* I'm still trying to work out, but you've massively helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're posting your collection as JSON, I reverse engineered what your actual collection would look like. Turns out, your `transform()` works fine as far as I can tell. Maybe that helps you to find differences between my and your collection which might lead you to your problem/solution:

```
$collection = collect([
  (object)[

    "allergens" => collect([
            (object)[
                "id" => 2001,
                "info" => "Allergy advice",
                "status" => "does_contain",
                "product_id" => 71576,
                "allergen_id" => 1,
                "allergen" => (object)[
                    "id" => 1,
                    "name" => "Celery"
                ]
            ],
            (object)[
                "id" => 2002,
                "info" => "Allergy advice",
                "status" => "may_contain",
                "product_id" => 71576,
                "allergen_id" => 11,
                "allergen" => (object)[
                    "id" => 11,
                    "name" => "Peanuts"
                ]
            ]
    ]),
  ]
]);
$collection = $collection->transform(function ($item, $key) {
    $item->allergens = $item->allergens->map(function ($allergen) {
        return [
            'id' => $allergen->allergen->id,
            'name' => $allergen->allergen->name,
            'status' => $allergen->status,
        ];
    });
    
    return $item;
});
dd($collection);
```

Result:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1779 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1791 ▼
      +"allergens": Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1775 ▼
        #items: array:2 [▼
          0 => array:3 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "Celery"
            "status" => "does_contain"
          ]
          1 => array:3 [▼
            "id" => 11
            "name" => "Peanuts"
            "status" => "may_contain"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating I'm doing the right thing. I was certain my approach was correct but seeing different behaviour, I'm investigating those differences now.

Comment: You're welcome. If you could update your question to reflect the steps I have done, @john-lobo and I can help you finding the differences.

Comment: I'm just trying to get a minimum reproducible example together, but it seems like the code is working now in isolation

Comment: Interesting. So it has to be something specific to your environment ...

Comment: Switching the allergens `map()` to `transform()` resolves, the issue, which would suggest that modifying the item in place, rather than returning a new collection and updating the `$item->allergerns` property is a suitable fix. They *why* I'm still trying to work out, but you've massively helped.